# Are min-device-width, max-device-width, and pixel ratio enough to exclude larger phones?

Tags: css, media-queries

The following media query meant to isolate the css within to iphone 5 and 5s is taking effect for 6, 6+, etc.. when tested on chrome in mobile mode.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

I don't have an actual device or a mac to simulate an actual device so I'm not sure if the query isn't specific enough or the dev tools in chrome are invalidating the test.  Will this work on actual phones or will it effect 6,7,8+ as it is in chrome?

Comment: `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` are sufficient for media queries specific for iphones, mac or other iOS products.

Comment: this media query doesn't effect the layout in other devices. I am not sure about `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` though.

Comment: What is the question? Are you trying to restrict the media query to iPhone 5 and 5s, but Chrome also uses it for iPhone 6 in emulation mode? In that case, haven't you answered your own question? I mean, the iPhone 6 has a width of 375 pixels according to Chrome, which is less than 568. Not sure what else to say.

Comment: @MrLister I don't understand your point.  375 is less than the max which is 568 so.. what?

Comment: Are these exact values for portrait/landscape widths or are they ranges?  I guess that's my question.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you want to achieve. In the question title you say you want to "exclude larger phones", which I took to mean that you want the media query to affect the iPhone 5, but not the iPhone 6. Sorry if I misunderstood, but I really do not know what you want. Or what "portrait/landscape" has to do with it. (For the latter, you would need to use [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio) in the query.)